# Converting URL from input to link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input box and what ever is sent is displayed below using angular.js but if the input is a http url i am trying to convert it to a link. I referred to [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) this SO page..
I am able to convert it to the  tag but its not a link. Its just like any other text..

Fiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/JY3Za/1/

The HTML code :

```
<div ng-app>

<div ng-controller="URL">
  <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="save"  size="30"
      placeholder="enter a url"/>
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add"/>
</form>
  <h1>{{replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(show)}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

and the JS code..

```
function URL($scope) {
$scope.shoe="";

$scope.addTodo = function() {
$scope.show=$scope.save;
  $scope.replaceURLWithHTMLLinks=function(text) {

var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
};
};

}
```

PS: I didnt write the regular expression and it was taken from the above Stackoverflow link for testing..

Comment: Here's a similar issue: [This might help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690804/insert-and-parse-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind to a value with HTML in it, you should use `ngBindHtml`, as documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). The regular bindings (in the form of `<span>{{ foo }}</span>`) prevent injecting actual HTML for security reasons.

If you use a recent-enough version of AngularJS, also keep in mind the restrictions of `$sce` documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce), that will require a little bit of extra work to tell AngularJS that the string is safe.

```
<h1 data-ng-bind-html="yourBindingHere"></h1>
```

As a sidenote, your `replaceURLWithHTMLLinks` can be made redundant with AngularJS's [linky](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) filter, available in the `ngSanitize` module:

```
<h1 data-ng-bind-html="yourBindingHere | linky"></h1>
```