# What wasy way to insert html item to exists template HTML in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What easy way to insert html item to exists template HTML in angularjs?
For example there is template generated in PHP:

```
<div id="block">
<!-- Insert here template from Angularjs-->
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I can Use Jquery like as:

```
$('#block').prepend('<div class="item"></div>');
```

How I can same in Angularjs?

Comment: Do you mean something like [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)?

Comment: I mean when I get data from socket.io I wanna to insert data in exists `div`

Comment: angular.element has both prepend and append methods just like jquery.  It's doubtful if they should be used but they certainly can be. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690804/insert-and-parse-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: But id I want change variable angulars by Jquery, is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to add HTML but you'll need to compile it first using

```
var compiledHTML = $compile(html)($scope);
```

and then pass it on to jquery's method

```
$('#block').prepend(compiledHTML);
```

But as @cerad mentioned definitely this is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular's data binding, you can also treat is as a template engine.

eg:

your html code is this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="msg in allMsgs">{{msg}}</li>
</ul>
```

your controller code is this

```
app.controller($scope){
   $scope.allMsgs = [];

   // i dont know socket.io well, so this part may not work :)
   // and it's better to separate it to a service and use $rootScope.$apply()
   soceket.on('msg',function(msg){
     $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.allMsgs.push(msg);
     });
   });
}
```

Note you need to use `$apply` in order to make the data binding work when data is
changed by events that angular doesn't control.

Some useful links

- [a blog about angular socket-io](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-socket-io)
- [$apply doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)