# Angularjs render view with scope values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a view like this:

```
  <div ng-show="">
<div style='background-color: #13a4d6; border-color: #0F82A8'>
    {{headerdescription}}
    <div style='float: right'>{{price}} $</div>
</div>
<div style=' width: 60%; float: left;'>
    <div style='padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;'>{{description}}</div>
    <div style='padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;'>{{softvalues}}</div>
</div>
<div style='float: right; margin-top: 10px;'>
    <img src='data:image/png;base64,{{image}}'>
</div>
```

And i want i my angular code to get this view with the scope values set.

I tried this:

```
  $scope.headerdescription = "YEEES";
                    $http.get('App_JsQuote/directives/door.html').success(function (html) {
                        console.log(html);
                    });
```

but the problem is that the scope-values are not set and therefor the view becomes as before. How can i set the scope-values and then get the view with all the data that should be there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690804/insert-and-parse-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute` or `ui-router`?

Comment: Are you trying to inject html? It looks as if someone has written a directive (judging from the URL), in which case, you wouldn't use `$http.get`, but instead use the directive itself.

Your ng-show expression will evaluation to falsy (`ng-show=""`).

[Here's a plnkr for the ng-show](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgjARFdJOk84PTvOm50C?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you try with something like this ?

```
$scope.headerdescription = "YEEES";    
$scope.apply(function() {
    $http.get('App_JsQuote/directives/door.html').success(function (html) {
          console.log(html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can need to use the [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive globally in the controller or use the [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive in the element. In the case you need to create media or link uri you need to use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service.

Example:

```
<div ng-show="">
    <div style='background-color: #13a4d6; border-color: #0F82A8'>
        <span ng-bind="headerdescription"></span>
    <div style='float: right' ng-bind="price + '$'"></div>
</div>
<div style=' width: 60%; float: left;'>
   <div style='padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;' ng-bind="description"></div>
    <div style='padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;' ng-bind="softvalues"></div>
</div>
<div style='float: right; margin-top: 10px;'>
    <img ng-src='url'>
</div>
```

In your JS file you need to use $sce to filter and generate the url var.

Example:

```
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('data:image/png;base64,' + $scope.image);
```